# Scrolling one UIScrollView Proportionately to Another

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2, xcode7

I have two UIScrollViews with vertical scroll: `foreground` and `background`. The user can only interact with the former; the latter is moved programmatically. How can I make it so that when the user scrolls the `foreground`, the `background` scrolls at a proportional rate of ¼? For example, for every 4px that `foreground` scrolls, `background` will scroll 1px in the same direction.

How can I achieve this relationship in Swift2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set your self as the scrollView delegate -

```
self.foregroundScrollView.delegate = self
```

and use the UIScrollViewDelegate methods:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    self.lastY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // Calculate how much distance the scrollView has travelled since last scroll
    CGFloat currentY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat difference = currentY - self.lastY;

    // Set new contentOffset for your background scrollView
    CGPoint currentBackgroundOffset = self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset;
    currentBackgroundOffset.y += difference/4;
    self.backgroundScrollView.contentOffset = currentBackgroundOffset;

    // Don't forget to update the lastY
    self.lastY = currentY;
}
```

Swift:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    lastY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Calculate how much distance the scrollView has travelled since last scroll
    let currentY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let difference = currentY - lastY

    // Set new contentOffset for your background scrollView
    var currentBackgroundOffset = backgroundScrollView.contentOffset
    currentBackgroundOffset.y += difference/4
    backgroundScrollView.contentOffset = currentBackgroundOffset

    // Don't forget to update the lastY
    lastY = currentY
}
```

Comment: Does this only update the scroll after the user's scroll has ended or does it do it simultaneously (virtually)?

Comment: @Dopapp It should looked like it gets updates simultaneously. I edited and updated the swift section, hope it makes sense.